# Looping Through a column and delete all rows below cells with specific value VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a sheet with 6 tables with each table using columns B:N. Column B contains hours from 1AM to 12AM per table. I need to delete all rows below the cells that contain a specific value on cell AF2. For example, AF2 contains 5PM. All rows below 5PM on column B on each table should be deleted.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub HideRows1()

Dim rCheck As Range
Dim rHide As Range
Dim rCheckCell As Range

Dim time1 As String

time1 = Sheet8.Range("AF2").Value

Set rCheck = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
rCheck.EntireRow.Hidden = False

For Each rCheckCell In rCheck.Cells
    If InStr(1, rCheckCell, time1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        If Not rHide Is Nothing Then Set rHide = Union(rHide, rCheckCell) Else Set rHide = rCheckCell
    End If
Next rCheckCell

If Not rHide Is Nothing Then rHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

End Sub

Comment: what your code does currently? what exactly is should do instead? Just stating what you need doesn't let us understand your problem. Also some sample data and explaining desired output can be helpful.

Comment: The problem with the above code is that it deletes everything below the cell which contains the value on cell AF2 on the first table. So it deletes all the other tables when it should just delete the other rows while retaining the tables

Comment: @Akina I updated the code above. What the above code does now is it only hides the row with the value in cell AF2. But then I need to have the other rows hidden/deleted as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is at least one empty cell in column B under the cell with `12AM` value, then

```vba
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet8")
Set cell1 = sh.Range("B1")
valueToFind = sh.Range("F2").Value
Do
    Set cell1 = sh.Range(cell1.Address & ":B" & sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Find(What:=valueToFind, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If cell1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set cell2 = sh.Range(cell1.Address & ":B" & sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count).End(xlDown)
    If IsEmpty(cell1.Offset(1, 0)) Then Exit Sub
    Rows(cell1.Offset(1, 0).Row & ":" & cell2.Row).Delete
    Set cell1 = cell1.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this also deletes the row with the value on cell AF2.. The row with the value on cell AF2 should stay and what should be deleted are the rows below the row with the value on cell AF2

Comment: @HomerL *this also deletes the row with the value on cell AF2* I cannot reproduce. Please share the worksheet file via GoogleDisk for to download and reproduce the problem.

Comment: I mean for example, cell AF2 says 12PM. The rows that should be deleted are the one with 1PM down to 12AM. In the case of the code above it deletes the 12PM row down to 12AM

Comment: @HomerL Check edited code. Additionally check that the cell immediately under each cell with the value of `12AM ` gives `True` for `IsEmpty(cell)`. If not then find proper criteria and edit according condition.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! :)